# com.mongodb.DB.authenticate(String,String) is in memory authentication or it make a call to mongo db?

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-java, nosql

I am writing a program where I am setting DB as the static variable in the class and I am using this db variable in every method when I am performing any CRUD operation.

```
public final class MongoDBUtil {

    private static MongoClient ejClient = null;

    private static DB db = null;

    /**
     * Prevent this class to creating the instance.
     */

    private MongoDBUtil() {

    }

    public static DB getDB() {
        if (db == null) {
            String userName = Property.INSTANCE.get("mongo.username");
            String pwd = Property.INSTANCE.get("mongo.pwd");
            String dbName = Property.INSTANCE.get("mongo.database.name");

            createMongoClient();

            db = ejClient.getDB(dbName);

          //db.authenticate will make a call to mongo db database or it's in memory call?

            boolean auth = db.authenticate(userName, pwd.toCharArray());

            if (!auth) {
                throw new EJException("Authentication failed for mongo db.");
            }
        }
        return db;
    }
}
```

The question has been put in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User accounts and permissions are stored on MongoDB (in the database `system`, to be precise). This means in order to authenticate, your application must connect to the database.

Comment: Thank you for the response.I need one clarification : MongoClient.getDB(dbName) does not fetch the credential in memory when we get the DB instance using MongoClient.getDB(dbName)?

Comment: @PradeepKrKaushal `getDB` does not even require to contact MongoDB. Authentication is only needed when you actually do something with the DB.

Answer (score 2):

As an aside, that authenticate has been deprecated in 2.12.  You should be using `MongoClient#MongoClient(java.util.List, java.util.List)` instead.